# Is this question understandable?

Tags: discussion

Given the fact that apparently a German, native speaker (according to his/her own words) is consistently criticizing my posts (the last one being [Fugen-s in Gefechtsstärke](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/43567/fugen-s-in-gefechtsst%c3%a4rke)), I'm wondering whether I'm actually that bad in posing questions or whether someone else is, perhaps, overly active? In addition to flagging and asking in chat, I'm asking here.

Comment: A last note: After at least 12 (zwölf!) [edits](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/43567/revisions) your question seemed to become understandable. Apparently most of your edits there, were triggered from comments asking for clarification. So I still don't see what's bad with criticism and interrogation for references and improvement in comments, about unusual and widely unknown terms heading your question.

Comment: I don't looked into detail but maybe it is a matter of German direct criticism which is a cultural problem of understanding. So please take the positive side from it. However also in English SE sites there are clear and strict voices which you could see as not very polite at all.

Comment: @MdAyquassar Either if it is cultural or personal driven please don't take it too serious and try to calm, with your will to edit and change your question you already showed much respect for the community. Don't give up and move on. ;-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 12 or even more edits is no criteria if a post is lacking quality in the end, please try to be more polite and patient to obvious new members. Blaming like this here is no help.

Answer (score 3):

In case you received comments that you feel are inappropriate for this site the appropriate thing to do is to flag them for moderator attention. In general we will not hesitate to delete any rude comments or comments that offend you and take further actions if necessary. Thank you for doing so in the past.

Please understand that we try to be active on the site as often as we can but we moderators are all in the same time zone. Hence a 24/7 service can not be provided. Sometimes there is a delay of a few hours until we can see flags.

Some differnces in personal opinions can lead to lengthy comment threads that won't help anybody and have to be cleaned up later. We do not want such over-long comment threads here.

To calm down a situation it is often better to not respond to any such rude or offensive comment. Also please take care to keep a calm and professional tone by yourself. If in doubt just move on and let others deal with it.

Comment: Hm. Unrelated to this case: "Offend you" or "are offending/offensive"? The first seems *awfully* subjective and so highly relative to differing cultural norms and practices as to be almost dangerously meaningless. Impossible as it is to get this onto an operationalised objective, or at least interpersonal congruent, level I guess some sheldonesque aspis as well as culturally inexperienced might benefit from a more spelled out guidelines (than those currently available).

Comment: @LangLangC _"and so highly relative to differing cultural norms and practices as to be almost dangerously meaningless."_ I have to agree to some point with that, yes. For my experience especially asian people would feel awkwardly insulted, if someone critiques or even only asks for more clarification. Doing such in an honest and direct way is considered _"rude"_ in their culture. Such things might become a frequent source of misunderstandings. At least I feel myself being a bit of offended since the OP did link my account here, just like putting me at a _pillory_.

Comment: @LangLangC: actually it is quite easy as there is no point in keeping content that offends an other user. This is even more so if **it was only a comment**.

Comment: @all: My comment is *not* about the case (which I cannot re-trace). It is about the difference of "flag what offends **you**" (fine rule of thumb) and "we will delete what offends **you**" (problematic rule of thumb). I argue that the latter case might benefit from a more 'canon' rule that is less subjective and more spelled out. Controversy is fine and should be. – I am not easily offended (*I* think, correctly?). I am not consciously offensive to people (*I* think, incorrectly?). – I guess: Better formulated rules beforehand, better feedback after 'incidents' are on my wish list.

Comment: @LangLangC: nothing we can do about different levels of tolerance, really. No rule on earth will change that. For moderating comments it is not an issue because they are very short lived temporary notes only which should be resolved in an edit of the post. Ideally not a single comment should stay but on this site we sort of tolerate them a bit longer because people believe they could learn a lot from such discussions. If however somebody gets offended by any such comment there is absolutely no reason why we should keep it.

Comment: For posts it is a bit different. See here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor for guides.

Comment: @Takkat Seems I am unable to entirely convince myself that "anyone who feels offended by sth" gets to decide what is removed (and I guess that is not really the case, actually. That might leave an impression of dancing between leeway and arbitrariness, tolerance and strictness). "Civil discourse" as an a priori remains quite ill-defined. But thanks for pointing to the diff re:"posts". In part I overgeneralised from "comments" to "content" here. – I still have a dream of universally defining what level of tolerance should be acceptable to anyone here, though the desired precision is unrealistic

Comment: @LangLangC: I can see that too - in fact it mostly is rather straightforward but of course this is not always the case. In difficult cases we discuss this in the moderator team, with the community here on Meta, with moderators on other sites, or in very obscure cases we also have ways to discuss matters with the StackExchange community managers.